# tinymce mcImageManager Configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, mcimagemanager

```
We have configured NFS (Network File Share) and created a Virtual Directory Link to NFS in the ASP.NET MVC Website. <br>
```

Here is the configuration.
    **\172.0.0.1\Webs\Images is Network File Share (from UNIX) 

    "https://www.testsite.com/Images"  - Virtual Directory Link to NFS**
    
    
    
    
    
    
    When we try to Insert an Image from tinymce editor, the MCImageManager does not show any images and it says "File/Folder was not found". Are there any other settings/permissions we are missing?

    Another question,
    Can we use MCImageManager on load balanced configuration? Our ASP.NET MVC site is load balanced and configured to use SQL Session State. Does it create any problem ?
    
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is probably too late for you, but since I just went through a slightly different exercise - I am using a folder outside of the website root, not a NFS.

So if you are storing images in a folder configured like this:

```
<!-- General file system options -->
...
<add key="filesystem.rootpath" value="C:/temp/Upload" />
...
```

and you configure the preview section like this:

```
<!-- Preview options -->
...
<add key="preview.wwwroot" value="C:/temp/Upload" />
<add key="preview.urlprefix" value="{proto}://{host}/ExternalImage/" />
...
```

And an image like this C:/temp/Upload/anawesomepic.jpg is going to be served at {proto}://{host}/ExternalImage/anawesomepic.jpg

TinyMCE then uses preview URL when inserting the image in edited document.

If you look at ImageManager source code in ImageManagerPlugin.cs you will see that at one point in OnCustomInfo method it calls this line:

```
info["thumbnail_url"] = man.ConvertPathToURI(thumbFile.AbsolutePath);
```

ConvertPathToURI is where the plugin removes the prefix defined in preview.wwwroot config item. Then ImageManager prepends that with preview.urlprefix, probably somewhere in javascript.

In my case I have an HttpHandler that handles images in ExternalImage, so the setup is definitely not quite like yours but maybe it helps.